# Рандом не целых чисел от 0 до 1

Tags: php

Какие есть функции в php которые смогли бы сгенерировать не целое число от 0 до 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[lcg_value:](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.lcg-value.php)

> Комбинированный линейно конгруэнтный генератор

Или что-то вроде: `mt_rand(0, 10)/10`

Comment: `lcg_value()` не знал, здорово!

А с `mt_rand()` желательно же максимизировать верхнее значение, для чего подходит `mt_getrandmax()`. С 10 будет всего макс. 10 разных значений между 0 и 1 – не айс )

Comment: Ну так то пример. Вместо 10 поставьте значение, соответствующее необходимой вам точности.

Comment: Кстати, периодичность [LCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) всего `2^32`, в то время, как периодичность [Mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) в `mt_rand()` – значительно больше: `2^19937 − 1`

Answer (score 3):

```
mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax()
```

Первая функция генерит случайное целое от 0 до максимального целого, а вторая возвращает это самое макс. целое.

В отличие от стандартного `rand()`, [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mt-rand.php) раза в 4 быстрее, и результаты гораздо более «случайные».

Answer (score 1):

```
$rand = rand (0,1000);

if ($rand!=0) $rand=$rand/1000;
```

Такой вариант подойдет?

Answer (score 0):

вот я придумал как генерировать не целое число от 0 до 100, например надо получить 36.418
Пример выводит 30 случайный чисел такого типа:

```
 for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++){
     $rand = mt_rand(0, 100) + (mt_rand(0, 10)/10) + (mt_rand(0, 10)/100) + (mt_rand(0, 10)/1000);
     echo "$rand</br>";
 }
```